# Is it good to develop view before model (in MVC pattern)?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model

I was wondering about the best practice when using the MVC pattern.

When you develop an app for a client, you want to think business. You want to think as the customer would. That's why I'm wondering :

Isn't it better to develop the view part, without any data treatment, so the customer can validate it ?

I see this practice as powerful as TDD is, I mean if you clearly know what your program will look like, you know which treatment it will require, making the model part a bit more concrete and business oriented, instead of making it too abstract and global.

I can not see downsides to this, so if you can see some, or explain me why it's not a good idea, please do.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main benefit, as I see it, would be the ability to provide the client with *hands-on* prototype.

It not uncommon for clients to change their mind, because often, when they hire a developer or company, they actually have only a **vague goal** for the end product. This way you would mitigate the risk of large scale changes late in the projects life-cycle.

As for implementation of such approach, I would recommend for you to look into concept of "[presentation objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html)" (Fowler has this annoying habit of slapping "model" on every damned term).

With presentation objects you would gain an ability to "shim" the data from *model layer*'s services. And it also would let you figure out, what exactly services (and service calls) will you *UI layer( interact with).

> <sub>**Note:** of course I am assuming that with "MVC" you do not mean some Rails-style abomination, where "views" are just dumb templates.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for answering. So if I understand correctly, it's not a bad idea but there is a particular way to do it. By the way yes, I was thinking about MVC as you use it in Java for instance.